# How to find out if two strings in two different Pandas dataframes are equal?

Tags: python, pandas, string, for-loop, isin

I have two different dataframes, A and B, which have a column each with a string. My goal is to loop through the string column in A and check if that string exists in B and if not, do some calculations with other columns in A and then write a new row to B with the values from A. I struggle with checking the string similarity.

i have tried this:

```
if A.string1.isin(B.string2.any() :
```

I get a TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

I have also tried with a for loop on A:

```
for value in A.itertuples() :
  if value.string1.isin(B.string2.any()) :
```

Then I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Sample data:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["john doe", " john doe", 'John'], 'B': [6, 7, 8]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'C': ["john dow", " john dough", 'john doe'], 'D': [9, 10, 11]})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please provide a example data

Comment: Sure!
`A = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["john doe", " john doe", 'John'], 'B': [6, 7, 8]})`
`B = pd.DataFrame({'C': ["john dow", " john dough", 'John doe'], 'D': [9, 10, 11]})`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: [Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
A.string1.isin(B.string2)
```

For all False that you receive you can modify your code accordingly.

Comment: I tried this, but I get AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 

di1 = {"A":["a","b","c","d"],"B":["a","b","c","d"]}

di2 = {"A":["a","45","c","d"],"B":["a","b","c","d"]}

data1 = pd.DataFrame(di1) #first dataframe
data2 = pd.DataFrame(di2) #second dataframe

for value in list(data1.A):
  if value in list(data2.A) :
      print(value) # print only if values are common in two dataframes
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The problem is that in the for loop I need to do calculations on other columns in A. When I just loop through the values in the list of values in one column, I cannot retrieve the corresponding values in other columns in order to perform these calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

```
for value in A.itertuples() :
  if value.A in list(B.C) :
    do calculations on other columns in A
```